# How to authorize my Web API Service?

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-web-api, authorization, unauthorized

I have download a project from the ASP.NET site: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

In which, The service should be available only for what are the user names mentioned in the Authorize annotation like following.

```
[Authorize(Users="Alice,Bob")]
```

So If the user name is other than the 'Alice and Bob', then only it shows Unauthorized user message. I added the above given annotation to my controller and tried the url but it shows Unauthorized user message always.So how to secure my Web API ?. please anybody give some example code for authorize my web api service.

Comment: How do you log on to the server?

Comment: I didn't log in, Just gave the URL and its working fine. Now I want to authorize the service, So how to do that ?

Comment: Okay, so you don't log in at all? How do you expect the service to know your user name?

Answer (score 0):

depending on the instructions you followed, there are either no users called Alice,Bob or you aren't logged in as them (provided you have followed all other instructions correctly)
follow these guidelines on the same site that you have posted:
[Authentication and Authorization in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api)
[Secure a Web API with Individual Accounts and Local Login in ASP.NET Web API 2.2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api)

Comment: Yeah, I tried this link, but I don't know how to implement the HttpResponseMessage Get() method, So could you please help me?

Comment: look at the second link in my comments. generally you can make http get requests using any http client package
https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html

Answer (score 0):

Check this it's a great series of blog posts to implement Authorization using Json Web Token. It's a bit complex but a complete tutorial and JWT ofc has many benefits

http://bitoftech.net/2015/01/21/asp-net-identity-2-with-asp-net-web-api-2-accounts-management/